# Julia convert UInt32 to UInt8 vector

Tags: julia

I have the following code and I need to covert several UInt32 variables to UInt8 vectors so then combine them into a single UInt8 vector.

The goal is to take the record I have decoded from a Pcap file and put it into a format that I can append to the end of an existing Pcap file.

The code below takes output from a previous function and returns a hex output of 4 UInt 32's and a vector of UInt8's for the payload.

```
function pcap_get_record(s::PcapOffline)
rec = PcapRec()
if (!eof(s.file))
    rec.ts_sec   = s.is_big ? read(s.file, UInt32) : ntoh(read(s.file, UInt32))
    rec.ts_usec  = s.is_big ? read(s.file, UInt32) : ntoh(read(s.file, UInt32))
    rec.incl_len = s.is_big ? read(s.file, UInt32) : ntoh(read(s.file, UInt32))
    rec.orig_len = s.is_big ? read(s.file, UInt32) : ntoh(read(s.file, UInt32))
    rec.payload  = read(s.file, rec.incl_len)
    return rec
end
nothing
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: So I have solved this and I was overthinking what needed to be done.

I just wrote the UInt variable in their raw form and that did the trick.

```
write(pcap, rec.orig_len)   #this is a UInt32
write(pcap, rec.payload)    #this is a UInt8 vector
```

Original:
I was having a hard time making my previous comment readable.

Thanks for the response. I am not however able to get the reinterpret to work with my UInt32 variable.

```
a = reinterpret(UInt8, rec.ts_usec) |> Vector
ERROR: bitcast: argument size does not match size of target type
Stacktrace:
[1] reinterpret(::Type{UInt8}, ::UInt32) at .\essentials.jl:370
[2] top-level scope at none:0

typeof(rec.ts_usec)
UInt32
```

after messing around some more I was able to get this to work but this doesn't seem very efficient.

"Edit" I just found that this wont work since it cuts off any leading zeros in the UInt32. example rec.incl_len = 0x00000516 would come out as "516" instead of "00000516" which is needed.

```
julia> hex(n) = string(n, base = 16, pad = 2)
julia> a = hex2bytes(hex(rec.ts_sec))
4-element Array{UInt8,1}:
0x5b
0x60
0xa3
0xa1
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you are

```
julia> reinterpret(UInt8, rand(UInt32, 1)) |> Vector
4-element Array{UInt8,1}:
 0x4d
 0x54
 0x34
 0xd3
```

remember to check the byte order.

Comment: Thanks, I cant seem to use this with my UInt32 variable.  
a = reinterpret(UInt8, rec.ts_usec) |> Vector  
ERROR: bitcast: argument size does not match size of target type  
Stacktrace:  
 [1] reinterpret(::Type{UInt8}, ::UInt32) at .\essentials.jl:370  
 [2] top-level scope at none:0  

typeof(rec.ts_usec)  
UInt32

Comment: @Zak21 Hi, sorry I didn't make it clear, the second argument should be a vector. `a = reinterpret(UInt8, [rec.ts_usec]) |> Vector` should work.